# mySQL, setting a field as the value from another field

Tags: mysql, subquery

A the moment I have two separate queries.

```
 Select `entity_id`,`parent_id`,`name`,`meta_description`
  from catalog_category_flat_store_1
  where level = 3 
  and is_active = 1
  order by parent_id asc, position asc
```

Which gives me an output like this:

```
+-----------+-----------+------------+----------+
| entity_id | parent_id | Name       | desc     |
+-----------+-----------+------------+----------+
|       1   |      0    |      test  | text     |
+-----------+-----------+------------+----------+
```

I have a separate query like this,

```
Select `entity_id`,`parent_id`,`name`,`meta_description`
      from catalog_category_flat_store_1
      where level = 2 
      and is_active = 1
      order by parent_id asc, position asc
```

Which gives me an output like this:

```
    +-----------+-----------+------------+----------+
    | entity_id | parent_id | Name       | desc     |
    +-----------+-----------+------------+----------+
    |       2   |      1    |      test2 | text     |
    +-----------+-----------+------------+----------+
```

I need to combine these two queries, so that the output looks like this:

```
    +-----------+-----------+------------+----------+
    | entity_id | parent_nm | Name       | desc     |
    +-----------+-----------+------------+----------+
    |       2   |      test |      test2 | text     |
    +-----------+-----------+------------+----------+
```

I've attempted to create a sub query to do this but I'm having no joy, could anyone suggest how the query might be structured. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you want?
Rather than a subquery, join the table to itself - you need to use aliases to distinguish between the two instances of the table. You may need to modify the "order by" to get the ordering you require - as your example had only 1 result, I guessed.

```
Select a.`entity_id`,b.`Name` as `parent_nm`,a.`name`,a.`meta_description`
from catalog_category_flat_store_1 a
join catalog_category_flat_store_1 b on a.`parent_id`=b.`entity_id` and b.`level`=3 and b.`is_active`=1
where a.level = 2 
and a.is_active = 1
order by a.parent_id asc, b.parent_id asc, a.position asc, b.position asc
```